# filter a featurelayer for several values of a specific property mapbox gl js

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

> I'd like to filter a feature layer for several values of a specific
> property,
> something like

```
"filter":["==","COUNTY",[array of filter values]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

With `match`

```
"filter" : [
  "match",
  ["get", "COUNTY"],
  ["County1", "County2", ... ],
  true,
  false
]
```

With `in`:

```
"filter" : [
  "in", 
  ["get", "COUNTY"],
  ["literal", ["County1", "County2", ... ]]
]
```

With `any`:

```
"filter" : [
  "any", 
  ["==", ["get", "COUNTY"], "County1"],
  ["==", ["get", "COUNTY"], "County2"],
  ...
]
```

Comment: you my good sir are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
"filter" : [
  "match",
  ["get", "COUNTY"],
  ["County1", "County2",...],
  true,
  false
]
```

You can read more about Mapbox GJ JS Expression on this page:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#match

Sometimes you can do the edits in Mapbox Studio as check the code behind to reuse in JS later.
Screenshot: https://ibb.co/z5D8rh3